# Default databases gone missing from Snowflake trial account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am learning Snowflake with a trial account and all the default databases were visible however, I logged in today and can see only one default database visible viz. SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA. I am logged in as ACCOUNTADMIN and don't see a reason why. Is anyone aware if this is a recent update for trial account holders or this is some setting for the same?

Comment: There are two places to set your role. The one in the top right with your login name controls the role you're using for the button bar. There's another place to set your role for the worksheets. It's on the right just under the tabs for the worksheet. You can click the people icon to change role, or you can run this sql:  use role sysadmin; (or accountadmin if required). Check that first because it's an easy thing to miss on new trials.

Comment: This helped. I was not aware the role needs to set under worksheet tab separately even if it's selected on top right. Thanks @GregPavlik..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Default databases should be available and probably the context is not set correctly after you login.

I see that you mentioned that you logged in as a ACCOUNTADMIN. This role should have the privileges to view all the databases available in the account. Click on the Database tab and you should see all the databases listed.

From the worksheet, you can select the role (by default it will be sysadmin) change this to accountadmin. Once this is done, when you click the dropdown it will list all the databases from where you choose the correct database and schema.

Other way is to run the commands manually like

```
use role accountadmin;
use warehouse testl;
use database SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA;
use schema public;
```

Hopefully, this will help you in future. Thanks